# Android | Firestore Rules | Check if username & phone already exists

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to check if the user's username and phone number is unique. I have implemented it using
`FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").whereEqualTo("phone",ph).get().addOnCompleteListener(...);`

This is my firestore rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
        allow read: true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
      match /Users/{userID} {
            allow update: if request.auth.uid == userID 
                && (request.resource.data.username == resource.data.username
               || isUserNameAvailable(request.resource.data.username)
            );
        }
  }
```

The code works fine with no issues. I am checking this before the `signInWithCredential` method and hence the request.auth.uid will always be null. To make the code work ill have to keep `allow read: true;`
But, now i am getting this warning

> We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
> any user can read your entire database

Is there any workaround to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake developers make when using `usernames`. You gave anyone permission to read your whole database. And even if you manage to put that to only read `Users` anyone could read all your users data.

I would recommend to remove the first `allow read:true` and write rules for each path as they should be. Also create a separated `collection` just for usernames and save all of them there like `/usernames/${username}` and `/phones/${phone}`. If the need to be saved together you can do that to.

That way you can very easy check without any query if a `username` or `phone` exists by just checking if that path exsists in your database.

You can very easy sync the `users` collection with those two and even write security rules that prevent creating users in the collection that have a `username` that already exists in the usernames collection.